# Google Play Game Services disconnects when user clicks on ad banner

Tags: android, google-play-games

I'm developing an Android game with multiplayer using Google Play Game Services. The game is working well, but one thing... An ad banner is displayed while players are playing, and if the user clicks on it, then the browser opens, and "onStop" is executed on my activity, and Game Services disconnects the player :(

Is there any way to solve it? I would like players could see ads without disconnecting :(

Answer (score 1):

Try to capture the onclick event, than pause the app, and forward the event to browser's call

Comment: I've already made some like this, not for Android Game, but I guarantee that It is possible :)

Comment: But I don't understand how to solve my problem capturing onclick :(

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove any code relevant to disconnecting from your onStop() method.
2. If #1 is already solved, then it seems to be an issue with the AD-SDK that you are using.

My game implements AdMob SDK and the client is not disconnected when clicking on an ad even though the browser opens.

Let me know if you want any other help.

Comment: The code that disconects is in GameHelper.java file from Google. The line that disconnects is commented with "this is very important (prevents resource leaks!)"... so I think removing it would not be a good idea... is it?

Comment: Not suggesting you modify the GameHelper code. Just ensure that the GameHelper onStop is not called even if application is going to background.

Comment: My Activity extends BaseGameActivity (written by Google), and this class calls mHelper.onStop() on its onStop method...